# Missing statement before else

Tags: c

I'm trying this basic code block to familiarize myself with conditionals. I don't think I haved missed a parenthesis or anything, however I get an error that I am missing a statement before the second else clause, but I don't understand this.

```
#include stdio.h;
main()
{
    int a = 2;
    int b = 4;
    int c = 6;
    int d = 8;
    if ( a > b )
    {
        a = a - 1;
        printf("a = %d ", a);
    }
    else
    {
        if ( b >= c )
        {
            b == b ? : 2;
        }
        printf("b = %d ", b);
    }
    else
    {
        if ( c > d)
        {
            c = c + d;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        d = d / 2;
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: The downvote seems unnecessary...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is the same as yours, indented in one of several more orthodox styles.

```
int main(void)
{
    int a = 2;
    int b = 4;
    int c = 6;
    int d = 8;

    if (a > b)    
    {
        a = a - 1;
        printf("a = %d ", a); 
    }
    else
    {
        if (b >= c)   
        {
            b == b ? : 2; // Syntax errors here too (and statement with no effect?)
        }
        printf("b = %d ", b); 
    }
    else
    {
        if (c > d)
        {
            c = c + d; 
        } 
    }
    else
    {
        d = d / 2;
    }
}
```

As you can see, there are 3 consecutive `else` clauses, where you are only allowed one.

There are also other syntax problems.

Answer (score 3):

If you properly indent your code, you'll see the problem:

```
} else {
    if ( c > d) {
        c = c + d; 
    } 
} else {
    d = d / 2;
}
```

Comment: I don't see the problem? The if is within the else, and the other else is self contained?

Comment: @SonnyOrdell: No; the `if` is not with the `else`, since there's an extra `}` in the middle.  Pay attention to the indentation.

Comment: The if is within the else as c = c + d is surrounded in parentheses, and that whol;e if block is within parentheses for the else clause?

Comment: The problem was with multiple else statements, not the parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

The structure of C could have only one else statement for an if statement. Instead it could have several elseif statements. Adding more number of else statements for an if statement will report an error on its syntax.

The error in your program states that the second else must have an if before it.
So convert all your intermediate else statements with nested if into elseif statements. Leave the last else statement as it is, you can get out of that error.

Answer (score 0):

In C programming
if .. else.. like this

```
 if( condition 1 )
        statement1;
     else if( condition 2 )
        statement2;
     else if( condition 3 )
        statement3;
     else
        statement4;
```